# How to identify the distribution of the given data in Python?

Tags: python, statistics, distribution

I have some data and want to find the distribution that fits them well. I found [one post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22425475/how-to-do-data-fitting-to-find-the-distribution-of-given-data) in`MATLAB` and [one post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31741742/how-to-identify-the-distribution-of-the-given-data-using-r) in `r`. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21623717/fit-data-to-all-possible-distributions-and-return-the-best-fit) talks about a method in Python. It is trying different distributions and see which one fits better. I was wondering if there is any direct way (like `allfitdist()` in `MATLAB`) in Python.

Comment: `It is trying different distributions and see which one fits better` What do you think `allfitdist` does internally?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo, yes, I agree that `allfitdist` is trying different distribution. I was just wondering if there is any similar command in Python that take care of it directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Fitter` in python provides similar functionality. The code looks like:

```
from fitter import Fitter
f = Fitter(data)
f.fit()
```

For more information, please take a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fitter